# magento product name move to breadcrumbs block

Tags: php, magento, product, breadcrumbs

As title I like to move my product name inside breadcrumbs.phtml. the following are the codes I currently have. But it returns a "Fatal error: Call to a member function getName() on a non-object". how can we fix this?

```
<?php if($crumbs && is_array($crumbs)): ?>
<?php $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output'); ?>
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>

<div class="breadcrumbs">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="container-inner">
            <ul>
                <?php foreach($crumbs as $_crumbName=>$_crumbInfo): ?>
                    <li class="<?php echo $_crumbName ?>">
                    <?php if($_crumbInfo['link']): ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo $_crumbInfo['link'] ?>" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_crumbInfo['title']) ?>"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_crumbInfo['label']) ?></a>
                    <?php elseif($_crumbInfo['last']): ?>
                        <strong><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_crumbInfo['label']) ?></strong>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_crumbInfo['label']) ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php if(!$_crumbInfo['last']): ?>
                        <span><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> </span>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    </li>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>

            <div>
                <h1><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></h1>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per as magento code , breadcrumbs are called at every page.

In your code,You have tried to call  `$this->getProduct();`  which is only working on product view at some blocks and it does not work on  breadcrumbs.

***If you have try to calling this breadcrumbs at every page then you get same  error.***

That we need to stop calling of `<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>`
 and `<?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></h1>`

at every page.

And ***getting product data at breadcrumbs then you need to call registry variable*** `Mage::registry('current_product')`.

see details at [Magento: How to tell if you're on a category page, or product page in .phtml file(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3503842/magento-how-to-tell-if-youre-on-a-category-page-or-product-page-in-phtml-fil)

```
 <?php if( Mage::registry('current_product')):?>
<div>
<h1><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute(Mage::registry('current_product'), Mage::registry('current_product')->getName(), 'name') ?></h1>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```